# Como fatorar n! ou !n?

Tags: python-3.x, fatorial

Como fatorar um número?

n! ou !n

Exemplo:

Vamos tomar x = 5

```
 x = input('Digite um número inteiro: ')
 i = 1
 while i <= x:
      for i in range(x):
        i = i + 1
        a = []
        a.append(i)
        print(a)
      break
```

Sendo que o resultado deve ser 120, no entanto o interpretador imprime isso:

```
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
[5]
```

Com 'append' consegui imprimir 'i' de 1 até 'x'. No exemplo acima, 'i = 1' e 'x = 5'.
O que eu não consigo é multiplicar 'i' de 1 até 'x'!

Comment: De muitas formas. Como você tentou fazer e qual foi a dificuldade encontrada?

Comment: Seja bem vindo, considere visitar os links informados acima. Se está tentando se tornar um programador, não é uma boa ajuda responder com um algorítimo pronto, aqui mesmo no site já existem uma série de respostas. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fatorial+python , mas dessa forma você estaria sendo ajudado a não ser um programador. Tente escrever um código, representado o problema, passo a passo, e [edit] sua questão colocando a dificuldade que encontrar.

Comment: Já pesquisou [nessas perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+fatorial)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está complicando demais:

```
x = 5
total = 1
for n in range(x):
    total = total * (n + 1)


print(total)
```

Comment: Com certeza eu compliquei demais. Vou estudar mais o 'range'.

Comment: O range vai de 0 a x-1